# Create a custom control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have this HTML code:

```
<select id="dummy4" name="dummy4" class="myselectbox">
<option>....</option>
    <optgroup label="Agent1">
    <option>Subagent1.1</option>
    <option>Subagent1.2</option>
    <option>Subagent1.3</option>
    <option>Subagent1.N</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Agent2">
    <option>Subagent2.1</option>
    <option>Subagent2.2</option>
</optgroup>
...
```

Is it possible to create a custom control from that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a section on MSDN about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx

Specifically, the walkthrough looks useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx